# Laptop with External Monitor and lid closed wont idle or sleep

Tags: windows, idle

I have a Windows 10 laptop and I use it as a desktop at times with a external monitor connected via HDMI.  When i work on the computer with the lid closed the computer never goes to sleep at the specified time.  Also it doesnt even idle as my Skype status never changes from green.

If i keep my laptop lid open everything seems to be fine.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Get a dock for the laptop and hook the monitor to the dock. Then it will work exactly like a laptop (assuming Power Management settings are correct).  All our customer laptops needing this facility have docks and all works well.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this same problem before... It seems that when you close the lid, it changes you primary screen from your laptop to your monitor.

The only solution that I've found it just to put it into sleep before closing the lid (Though when you have it in sleep you don't really need to close the lid).

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the advanced power plan settings in windows.

I used to have the same problem back when I had my laptop hooked up to an external monitor and I believe I was able to fix this by tweaking the power plan settings.